# How to save and load rsa keys

Tags: python, json, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt some text and then save the ciphertext and the keys in separate files, then decrypting the "file" file (ciphertext) using the "keys" (keys in json)

Breakdown of my code

1. Creating keys
2. Opening keys file
3. Converting keys to json
4. Saving file
5. Getting text from user
6. Encrypting it
7. Writing ciphertext to file
8. Loading keys
9. Taking e, n, d, p, q values and assigning them
10. Opening and reading ciphertext from file
11. Decripting and outputting

All of the code works except when I try to assign the keys from my json file,
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python projects\encrption\test.py", line 48, in <module>
    text = rsa.decrypt(cyphertext, loadkedkeys[1]).decode()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\python projects\encrption\.venv\lib\site-packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 249, in decrypt
    decrypted = priv_key.blinded_decrypt(encrypted)
TypeError: blinded_decrypt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'encrypted'
```

My code:

```
import rsa
import json

#make keys
print("new keys")
loadkedkeys = rsa.newkeys(256)
print("file")
#turn keys into json
keysfile = open(file=("kes"), mode="w")
keys = {"keys": []}
keys["keys"].append(((loadkedkeys[0].e), (loadkedkeys[0].n)))
keys["keys"].append(
    (((loadkedkeys[1].e), loadkedkeys[1].n, (loadkedkeys[1].d), (loadkedkeys[1].p), 
(loadkedkeys[1].q))))
keysfile.write(str(json.dumps(keys)))
keysfile.close()

text = input("message: ")
#encrypt
cyphertext = rsa.encrypt(text.encode(), loadkedkeys[0])

keysFile = open(file="kes", mode="r")
keysfilecontents = keysFile.read()
try:
    keys = json.loads(keysfilecontents)
except:
    print("json error")

loadkedkeys = (rsa.key.PublicKey, rsa.key.PrivateKey)
# setting public key
loadkedkeys[0].e = keys["keys"][0][0]
loadkedkeys[0].n = keys["keys"][0][1]
# setting private key
loadkedkeys[1].e = keys["keys"][1][0]
loadkedkeys[1].n = keys["keys"][1][1]
loadkedkeys[1].d = keys["keys"][1][2]
loadkedkeys[1].p = keys["keys"][1][3]
loadkedkeys[1].q = keys["keys"][1][4]
keysFile.close()

print(loadkedkeys[0])
print(loadkedkeys[1])

open("text.txt", "wb").write(cyphertext)

text = open("text.txt", "rb").read()

text = rsa.decrypt(cyphertext, loadkedkeys[1]).decode()

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I seem to have figured it out, I changed so I assign the values though rsa.PublicKey(value,value), also swapped the e and n values